# Rails render partial mobile format of view instead of html format

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nginx, passenger

I have both mobile and web versions of my rails project, and having problem with ajax calls on production. When I call this part of code on web version, it loads mobile version of site:

```
$("#items_grid #page").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/catalog_product', :formats => session[:mobile_param].to_i == 1 ? 'mobile' : 'html') %>")
```

Usually it works fine, but by passing *some period of time* after deploying it to webserver this miss happens. I can recover it again for a *some period of time* by adding some changes in **shared/catalog_product.html.erb** file. I guess webserver somehow saves this file in cache, and cannot see difference between **shared/catalog_product.mobile.erb** and **shared/catalog_product.html.erb**
I am using **nginx+passenger** for deploying project.
Also I checked, and sure that problem is not in `session[:mobile_param].to_i == 1`

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks` ? and where do you write this javascript code `$("#items_grid #page").html(....)`

Comment: Yes  I am using turbolinks. This code is written in *.js.erb file. I call it remotely

Comment: Can you please explain the flow of calls (how do you call this code remotely?, in a view or you call it from javascript?)

Comment: Yes I call it from view, when I click on link with attribute data-remote="true", I get Ajax effect, and needed *.js.erb file loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `data-no-turbolink` attribute `data-no-turbolink="true"` to opt-out this link from Turbolinks, this way the response of the ajax call won't be cached

More in:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/rails-4-a-look-at-turbolinks
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Comment: does turbolink stores in cache already pure js code, and it could be that, turbolink stored it when session[:mobile] == 1 was true? I don't want to refuse from turbolinks, I can separate logic from controller, and js files for html and mobile versions will be different. But it will be too dirty solution